# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

For a current research project, I am planning to read the JSON object "Main_Text" within a pre-defined time range on basis of Python/Pandas. When counting the unique words, the code however yields the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' indices must be integers` for line `if word in d:`.

I have alreay been through trouble-shooting threads and, among others, tried to set things up as a tuple (as recommended by some threads), which has overcome the error but led to an empty output. Is there any helpful tweak to make this work?

The JSON file has the following structure:

```
[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text"}
]
```

And the relevant code excerpt looks like this:

```
import string
import json
import csv

import pandas as pd
import datetime

import numpy as np


# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()


# Filtering by date
start_date = "01/01/2009"
end_date = "01/01/2015"

after_start_date = df["Date"] >= start_date
before_end_date = df["Date"] <= end_date

between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]

print(filtered_dates)


# Processing
for row in filtered_dates:
    line = list(filtered_dates['Text Main'])
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character

    line = [val.strip() for val in line]

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = [val.lower() for val in line]

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = [val.translate(val.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) for val in line]

    # Split the line into words
    words = [val.split(" ") for val in line]

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if word in d.keys()
```

Since 'd' is a dictionary you cannot do this :

```
if word in d: # does not work like this to check if something is present in a dictionary
```

I have made the required changes to your for loop :

```
for row in filtered_dates:
    line = row['Text Main']
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.split(' ')
    line = [val.strip() for val in line]

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = [val.lower() for val in line]

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = [val.translate(val.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) for val in line]
    print(line)
    # Split the line into words
    # words = [val.split(" ") for val in line]
    # print(words)
    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in line:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d.keys():
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1

print(d)
```

Comment: Good thought, it is leading to the same result however `(TypeError: unhashable type: 'list')`

Comment: Whats your filtered_dates printing exactly ? if you give the value of that variable i can try running from the 'for' loop

Comment: Filtered_dates is yielding the JSON lines within the pre-defined time frame. The values of the file look like this: `[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text 1"}, {"No":"122","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2016","Text Main":"Sample text 2"}
]`

Comment: before the 'for' loop of 'words' , if you print words you get :[['s'], ['a'], ['m'], ['p'], ['l'], ['e'], [''], ['t'], ['e'], ['x'], ['t'], [''], ['1']]

Comment: Your second statement is false. ```if word in d``` translates to ```if word in d.keys()```. You are checking if a hashable type exists in the dict keys.

Comment: list(filtered_dates['Text Main'])  should be   list(row['Text Main'])

Comment: OP, the error is that you are not inputting the key that you think you are. Please recheck your for loop and print to make sure your key is what you are expecting. It seems that your key is a list.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am currently checking how to amend the statement accordingly. Regarding the list: I had `list(row['Text Main'])` in the past, which yielded `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: @M.S.    => i have made changes to your for loop and the final print(d) outputs  ` {'text': 2, '1': 1, 'sample': 2, '2': 1}  `

Comment: This looks like the right output to me, many thanks. When replicating the code, I am howver still receiving the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` notification for `line = row['Text Main']`. Could that be related to the fact that I am importing and converting the JSON data beforehand?

Comment: if you add print statements in your previous code for 'line' and 'words' variables you will understand where you were going wrong . your 'line' looked like this : ['S', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', ' ', '1']    after first line inside loop itself .

Comment: yes it could be because your filtered_dates might be a string , I ran the code with ` filtered_dates = [ {"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text 1"}, {"No":"122","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2016","Text Main":"Sample text 2"} ]  `
which will be a proper list of dictionaries . you could try json.dumps() to get the right Type of 'filtered_dates'

Comment: Thanks for this - I had tried dumps() before but it has unfortunately not moved the needle. Let me see if I can figure out another way to solve this.